# Why use string.Empty over "" when assigning to a string object

Tags: c#

I've been running StyleCop over my code and one of the recommendations SA1122 is to use string.Empty rather than "" when assigning an empty string to a value.

My question is why is this considered best practice.  Or, is this considered best practice?  I assume there is no compiler difference between the two statements so I can only think that it's a readability thing?

[SO question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151472/what-is-the-difference-between-string-empty-and)

[Jon Skeet answer to question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263191/in-c-should-i-use-string-empty-or-string-empty-or)

Comment: I'm sure this was asked and answered on Stack Overflow - but I'm having trouble finding it. It's to do with the fact that it has to instantiate a new string object for `""` but not `string.Empty`

Comment: @ChrisF Ahh, didn't think to look on stack overflow for this type of question.  I'll have a gander.

Comment: dup of question on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151472/what-is-the-difference-between-string-empty-and

Comment: @ChrisF - It has been asked on SO. [Over](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263191/in-c-should-i-use-string-empty-or-string-empty-or) and [over](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3509402/why-do-we-need-to-use-string-empty-instead-of-using) and [over](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151472/what-is-the-difference-between-string-empty-and)...

Comment: Here we go - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151472/what-is-the-difference-between-string-empty-and - back from September 2008.

Comment: Roger that one, cheers

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263191/in-c-should-i-use-string-empty-or-string-empty-or.  John Skeet's answer currently has 154 up votes.

Comment: Well, I'm sure "" works fine if you're just hacking something together in your garage or whatever, but it's hardly suitable for a scalable enterprise solution. You need String.Empty for *that*.

Comment: Why doesn't the C# compiler just optimize `""` into `string.Empty` behind the scenes?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One valid reason is that it makes it clear this is not a typo or placeholder, that you *really* meant to use the empty string here.

I don't know if it's considered "best practice".

Comment: ""...this is not a typo or placeholder"".
Can you explain this 2 cases, I really don't see it.

Answer (score 8):

I'd imagine there are two reasons, one for readability, and two for a minor performance boost.

Readability is easy: it's a lot quicker to spot `string.Empty` than `""`.  Searching for `string.Empty` is also generally going to be easier and maybe more accurate than looking for the literal.  It also clarifies intent: you didn't just make a typo or forget to finish something, you really did want empty string.

The performance reason is due to [interning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.intern.aspx). You see, the runtime keeps a table of previously used strings so that it can quickly do string comparisons without actually doing a character-by-character check.  `string.Empty` is already an interned reference to `""` where-as typing the literal may not give you the interned version, thus causing a slight performance hit.

Comment: one nitpick, typing the literal "" will always give you the same interned version of "", at least since .Net 2 and up.

Comment: Right, the interning article on MSDN is a bit hard to follow on that point. It does seem like "" and string.Empty should both point at the same interned string, but it seems to indicate some differences between .net runtime versions.  I think any string literal that appears multiple times in code will be interned on the second and further uses, yes?

Comment: Also I should emphasize that when I say slight, I mean super-tiny.  "Because of performance" is not a reason to go switching from one representation to the other, it's just a neat thing worth knowing about the runtime.

Comment: It should also be noted that the performance aspect is only true for compilation. As both compile down to the same IL, the runtime performance should is identical.

Comment: that performance boost would only be on compile

Comment: This type of string management is done by the compiler

Comment: I really don't understand the _readability_ reason. I find _""_ much more readable  than _String.Empty_. I recognize it faster, plus it is shorter.
About typo: you cannot write a single (") or 3 double quotes ("""), so what typo mistake can you make?

Answer (score 7):

`string.Empty` wins in a really corner case, which can lead to some magical bug and really hard to debug:

If there is a [zero width space](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm) in `""`.

Answer (score 2):

According to some documentation I found, it has to do with what's emitted by the compiler.

A quick search reveals : http://stylecop.soyuz5.com/SA1122.html

Why it's filed under "Readability Rules" with that description is puzzling.

Comment: Updated link to SA1122 documentation: https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/blob/master/documentation/SA1122.md